# NodeJs project as a Azure WebJob

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, azure-webjobs

What is process to upload NodeJs project as Azure WebJob from Visual Studio.

I want to upload my nodeJs Project to azure as a WebJob from visual studio **with out a WebAPP** I am not able to find any blogs or articles to progress further.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to use git to upload your project to azure, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/

Answer (score 0):

There is an offical tutorial [`Deploy WebJobs using Visual Studio`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/) which you can refer to, but the deployment is within a WebApp.

However, I discovered a new preview feature `Azure WebJobs as Api App` on Azure new portal. I think it seems to satisfy your needs, please see and try at the [link](https://ms.portal.azure.com/?feature.relex=*%2CHubsExtension&flight=1#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryFeaturedMenuItemBlade/selectedMenuItemId/home/searchQuery/webjobs/resetMenuId/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This question is problematic, WebJobs run always in the context of a WebApp, that's what they are designed for.

In the meantime Microsoft published Azure Functions https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/
which can do mostly the same and more, only problem is you'll be developing more functional (haha) as global objects/settings/environment variables aren't accessible (because there is no WebApp context).